# Add "movie" to tag blacklist

Tags: feature-request, tags

Since "anime" and "manga" tags are blacklisted, "movie" should be blacklisted as well since it either serves the same purpose or overlaps with the usage of "variations"

Comment: +1 I agree 110%. If I could upvote this more than once, I would.

Comment: @Wipqozn I did that on your behalf. :)

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the "movie" tag should be blacklisted.  If users are asking questions that are specific to a movie then they're likely going to mention the name of the movie in the title or content of the question.

I used the movie tag on [this](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/430/when-does-the-deadzone-movie-take-place-in-the-dbz-storyline) question and even looking back at that question, the tag wasn't needed and I'll be removing it now.

Comment: To others: Don't start removing tags in packs. Questions will be bumped unnecessarily. Do it little by little.

Comment: Agreed.  I wasn't trying to start a mass removal of the tag or anything.  I just knew it wasn't necessary for the question I had tagged.

Comment: Yes yes I know, I didn't mean that. :P